# Mongo 4.0.3: Why is the SHARD_MERGE taking so much longer than everything else with a tiny result set?

Tags: mongodb, sharding

I have a cluster with 2 shards, a partitioned collection containing 3.6m records and an index covering the fields I'm querying.

A query I am running is showing that the query itself is taking a max of 250ms on the slower shard and is returning 59 records from each shard.

However, the SHARD_MERGE stage is taking around 8 seconds to merge these two result sets together.

The executionStats json is absolutely huge, so I won't put it in here, but below is a visual representation of the output, courtesy of NoSQL Booster.

[image: NoSQL Booster screenshot]

Any help diagnosing what is causing the major slowdown at what I would think would be a relatively quick operation would be greatly appreciated.

I'm happy to include any output that might be useful to help debug.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I've now removed bp-rs1, and am now running just on bp-rs0 to see what would happen. bp-rs0 is still only taking a max of maybe 490ms, but the stage above is now called SINGLE_SHARD and it's STILL taking way way longer. In my last test run, the SINGLE_SHARD step took 13.5 seconds, to bp-rs0's 490ms.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the hint method so that your query can be executed through a specific index. I encountered a similar problem in my environment. I can make the time of the SHARD_MERG phase drop drastically through the hint method. But I don't know why.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30601466)